# How to convert for loop into streams?

Tags: java, loops, collections, java-stream

How would I use streams to achieve the same result as below? I am trying to find the average of this 'tot' value by first iterating through TickQueue (a queue implementation) and summing tot, and then afterwards dividing by the counter value to find the average.

```
int counter = 0;
double tot = 0;

for (Tick t: TickQueue)
{
    if ((t.getAskPrice() == 0 && t.getBidPrice() == 0) || (t.getAskPrice() == 0) || (t.getBidPrice() == 0))
    {
        tot += 0;
    }
    else
    {
        tot += (t.getAskPrice() - t.getBidPrice());
        counter++;
    }
}

double avg = tot/counter;
```

Comment: What’s the point of `tot += 0;`? And why do you write a condition like `(A && B) || A || B`? The result of `A && B` has no effect on the outcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [`DoubleStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html) for `sum/average/count`:

```
double avg = tickQueue.stream()
    .filter(t -> t.getAskPrice() != 0 && t.getBidPrice() != 0)
    .mapToDouble(t -> t.getAskPrice() - t.getBidPrice())
    .average()
    .orElse(0.0);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
TickQueue.stream().
filter(t -> !((t.getAskPrice() == 0 && t.getBidPrice() == 0) || (t.getAskPrice() == 0) || (t.getBidPrice() == 0)).
forEach(t -> {
    tot += (t.getAskPrice() - t.getBidPrice());
    counter++;
});
```

You first filter out the values where `((t.getAskPrice() == 0 && t.getBidPrice() == 0) || (t.getAskPrice() == 0) || (t.getBidPrice() == 0))`, and then for the remaining values calculate tot and counter.

Comment: This wouldn't actually compile, because `tot` and `counter` are not effectively final.